# Getting each character from a textfile in my 2DgridArray

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, transform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FldmL.jpg)
you cann see at the picture that he is not printing out some strange letters and the white spaces are sometimes not included.
The output is not right and i don't know where these strange letters come from .. maybe the transfer is not right ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int xarrSize = 15;
    const int yarrSize = 65;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    char c;
    char grid[xarrSize][yarrSize];
    fstream input;

    input.open("map.txt", fstream::in);
    if (!input)
    {
        cout << "not open";
    }

    while (input >> noskipws >> c)
    {
        grid[x][y] = c;
        y++;
        if (c == '\n')
            x++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xarrSize; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < yarrSize; ++j)
        {
            cout << grid[j][i];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}



Is it possible to filtering each character for example my textfile is just some letters like A,B,C

I want that to transform this into my gridarray, to work with the letters to build my game.

But i tried like other ways and searching in youtube and stackoverflow and non of these helped me. 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2HWs.jpg
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use ````std::vector```` or ````std::array```` or in general the C++ STL, including algorithms?

Comment: yes i can use all

Comment: If you want to parse comma-separated file, you have to filter out commas. Your while loop is error-prone because there is easy way to get array out of bounds (if you have more characters then `xarrSize*yarrSize` in file). Beside that I think your intent is to increment `y` on every row (`x++; if (c == '\n') y++;`. As @ArminMontigny wrote, using STL containers will make your code more C++

Comment: One more thing, you have to zero `x`/`y` on every `y`/`x` increment.

Comment: i just have letter like A     B     C 
no commas there but i will look at the stl-container and will look forward to use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following i suggest a solution which adresses following points:

1. When the file could not be opened the program should terminate instead of dealing with non existant data
2. Grid should be initialized. I used '.' for this, but any other printable character will do
3. The program should not exceed array boundaries. Therefore the while loop was replaced by a nested for loop regarding the array boundaries
4. Tabs were converted to single space in the output to make it more regular
5. Linebreaks were not placed in the output to have consistent rows of data
6. For visualization reasons i added a column counter at the top (this may be removed again). It was added just for demonstration purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int xarrSize = 15;
const int yarrSize = 65;

int ReadArray(int xsize, int ysize, char grid[xarrSize][yarrSize], istream &input){
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < xsize; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ysize; ++j)
        {
            if ( !(input >> noskipws >> c) ){
                return i*ysize+j;
            }
            if (c == '\n') break;
            if (isspace(c)) c = ' ';
            grid[i][j] = c;                
        }
    }
    return xsize*ysize;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char filename[100] = {0};

    char grid[xarrSize][yarrSize];
    fstream input;

    memset(grid, '.', sizeof(grid));
    strcpy(filename, argv[0]);
    strcat(filename, ".cpp");

    input.open(filename, fstream::in);

    if (!input)
    {
        cout << "not open";
        exit(-1);
    }

    int readBytes = ReadArray(xarrSize, yarrSize, grid, input);

    if (readBytes == 0){
        cout << "Could not read file";
        input.close();
        exit(-2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < yarrSize; ++i)
    {
        cout << (char)('0' + i % 10);
    }

    cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < xarrSize; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < yarrSize; ++j)
        {
            cout << grid[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    input.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
    01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234

    0 1 00 01 10 11 000 001   010      011 ..........................
    100 101 110 111 .................................................
    0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 ...................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
    0110 0111 1000 1001 1010          1011 1100 1101 1110 ...........
         1111 10011 11001............................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
```

Comment: now i want it in QT -> so i can't display and work on point inside the grid.
Like q point from my array to create objects and go from that location.